# HTTP Error 404 with jetty server

Tags: jetty, classpath, maven-jetty-plugin

I have the following folder structure in my project.

```
> src/
>>main/
>>>webapp/
>>>>WEB_INF/
>>>>>pages/
>>>>>>js/
```

All my script files are located in js folder and my jsp page is located in pages folder.In order to include abc.js script in my jsp page I wrote the following line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WEB-INF/pages/js/abc.js"></script>
```

But I got following error

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF/pages/js/abc.js"
```

I am using jetty server to deploy my project. For running it I am using

```
mvn jetty:run
```

If I am putting my script file directly in webapp folder and including script  in following way then it is working perfectly fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js"></script>
```

But I want to maintain folder structure of my project by putting all scripts in js folder.
Can somebody please tell me why jetty server is taking files located only in webapp folder?
I am using windows7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `src` is incorrect. Java Servlet specifications states explicitly that **no document under `WEB-INF` directory will be available to the webserver**. You need to place your JavaScript file outside of it.

Usually, you place **jsp** files inside of it, because they're not accessed directly. They're accessed through a **Servlet** or any other web development framework in Java.

If you want to maintain your folder structure, just put your **js** folder on the web archive root:

```
webapp/
   js
   WEB-INF/
       classes/
       lib/
       pages/
       web-xml
```

`WEB-INF` directory was designed exactly to prevent that users could access files they should not get access to, such as `classes`, `lib` directories, or `web.xml` deployment descriptor.

Comment: So, these guys don't exist, or there's something you're missing?

http://restlet-discuss.1400322.n2.nabble.com/Serving-Directory-under-WEB-INF-td3890646.html

Comment: You can hack your way into `WEB-INF` directory. But you **won't** be able to access directly through the browsers as OP is intending to. Look at your URL. The hack is inside a Servlet or something similar from a different web framework. Not inside HTML/JS code.

Comment: That's fine, good information.  I assumed that since his structure was like that he'd got it working before and was just wondering why that particular script src wasn't working.  Either way, a re-structure is better so your answer is good.  Although it could be stated more accurately than absolutely.